# passing request body variables into script2 when importing

Tags: json, python-2.7, rest, flask

I am hoping someone can help me find a way to pass the variables I post when calling my POST service (script1) into script2 when it gets imported.

I have this script1 below as a POST rest service built using flask

```
from testingdf import *
from flask import Flask, json, request
app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route("/results", methods=['POST'])
    def createResults():
      entry = request.get_json().get('entry', '')
      passcode = request.get_json().get('passcode', '')
      print "**testing results**"
      print results
      response = app.response_class(
          response=json.dumps(results),
          status=200,
      mimetype='application/json'
      )
      return json.dumps(results)
```

I want to use script1 to call script 2 below and return script 2 output (results) as a json response from script 1 api:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()


number = [21, 44, 31, 553, 63, 35]
access = ["denied", "Try Again", "Retry", "Accepted", "Error", "Success"]


def mapping(entry, passcode):
    team = ''
    if entry in range(20,30):
        team = 'Revolt'
    elif (entry in range(40,50)) and (passcode == 'Try Again'):
        team = 'Strike'
    elif (entry in range(60,100)) and (passcode == 'Error'):
        team = 'Exception'
    return team

testInput = zip(entry, passcode)
for number, access in testInput:
    Team = mapping(number, access)
    df = df.append({'Access Message': access, 'Number': number}, ignore_index=True)


results = {
    'Entry' : number,
    'Outcome' : access,
    'team': team
    }
```

I used `from testingdf import *`  to import `script2` into `script1` however whenever I call my api it runs `script2` first and the `variables` that I pass in the request body return as unrecognized, which is an expected behavior since the imported module is executed first. Is there another way around this?

How can I import `script2` and it's variables without having it executed initially when I call my api?

Comment: Please include complete code, i.e. script1 code, too. Show the code depicting what exactly you tried.

Comment: @FarhatNawaz this the complete code in two separate scripts. I use script1 to serve as an post api endpoint that I call, then it goes and execute script2

Comment: Actually, this is the correct behaviour. Your doing ‘import *’, which means import everything from the file. For that, python would sift through the entire file and import everything. And since that import statement is on line 1, it seems as if script 2 is running first. But in real, script1 runs first. If you put that import statement somewhere in between script1, you’ll see that actually script one runs first.

Comment: @FarhatNawaz that is correct, which is why I am trying to explore other ways of referencing that file and variable without having it executed initially.